# Getting error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitLabel(org.objectweb.asm.Label)

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, pom.xml, wildfly-10

I am having two projects. One is spring mvc project which fires a JMS Message in to active mq and other which listens to this active mq and process it

Now I am using activemq configurations in both the projects. When I add the pom dependency in the first project as:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now when I deploy both the projects in Wildfly then I am getting an error as follows :

```
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154) [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar:1.2.6.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar:1.2.6.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:375)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:543)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.BusHolder.configure(BusHolder.java:234)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:97)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147) [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.visitLabel(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.createWrapperClass(WrapperClassGenerator.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.generate(WrapperClassGenerator.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.generatedWrapperBeanClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:675)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.getExtraClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:645)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:461)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:696)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:261)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:460)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:338)
    ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitLabel(org.objectweb.asm.Label)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionInvokationHandler.invoke(ReflectionInvokationHandler.java:85)
    ... 28 more
```

But without this dependency the both the applications run fine. So what is this error, and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems so to me, that you have an asm dependency in your package and JBoss also provides asm. The problem caused by different versions. I hope it helps: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/690353

Comment: I am not having any dependancy of asm. But I am having this dependancy

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
   <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
   <version>5.13.3</version>
  </dependency>

common in both the projects . Can this be causing the error?

Comment: I dont think so, because the message comes from the cxf stack. Could you make a dependency tree please?

Comment: Actually my dependency in pom are many so the dependency tree is very big. But I have made a dependency tree and I found 
 +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:4.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:4.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:4.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:4.0:compile 

dependancy in there

Comment: MethodWriter comes from org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0. You should change the scope to provided. But the problem could be more complicated, because these dependecies are old and I don't know, why you need them.

Comment: This org.ow2.asm comes from org.objectweb right? I have changed the scope of org.objectweb to provided but still the error is coming.
I have objectweb dependancy as follows :
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.objectweb.joram</groupId>
   <artifactId>jftp</artifactId>
   <version>1.52</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: It is not that jar. Do you have Eclipse? If you have opened your pom.xml, there is a tab with the name "Dependency Hierarchy". At the top is a filter, you should search the asm jar. You can check then, which dependency contains it. If you don't need it, you can exclude the jar.
You can easly override the scope in your pom.xml. You should only add this dependency :   
              <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
   <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
   <version>4.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help . Actually I checked the dependency diagram from intellij and found asm was coming from wro4j-extensions. So I added the scope to be provided and now it ran successfully without any errors.